# Import Separate Excel 2016 Worksheets into Separate Access 2016 Tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, excel-2016, ms-access-2016

First off, this is a compilation of code from various sources and as much as I would like to give credit, I cannot find the originator. My apologies.

Dilemma, I have 5 spreadsheets, all different names, there is one tab on each spreadsheet with the same name as the file and in Access there is a corresponding table name that is the same(keeping it simple.) In the code below, it imports the first worksheets tab data into the corresponding table in Access and prompts me with the message box saying it is done. However, none of the other tables are imported, which makes sense. I am missing a component to call each file versus just one worksheet. FYI, I cannot combine these files into one worksheet, because some of the worksheets have a ton of data. They are all .xlsb files. Am I missing a step?

```
Function Fnc_ImportData()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
Dim intWorksheets As Integer

 ' delete the current data in all 5 tables in Access
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_F2F_Alloc_tblDataDelete"
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_GDM_USD_tblDataDelete
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_GDM_USD_BDGT_tblDataDelete
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_IntraHR_Data_tblDataDelete
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_IT_ProjectCosts_tblDataDelete


 ' Replace (1 to #) with the number of worksheets to be imported
 ' from each EXCEL file
 Dim strWorksheets(1 To 5) As String

 ' Replace (1 to #) with the number of worksheets to be imported
 ' from each EXCEL file (this code assumes that each worksheet
 ' with the same name is being imported into a separate table
 ' for that specific worksheet name)
 Dim strTables(1 To 5) As String

 ' Replace generic worksheet names with the real worksheet names;
 ' add / delete code lines so that there is one code line for
 ' each worksheet that is to be imported from each workbook file
 ' strWorksheets(1) = "GenericWorksheetName1"
 strWorksheets(1) = "tbl_F2F_Alloc"
 strWorksheets(2) = "tbl_GDM_USD"
 strWorksheets(3) = "tbl_GDM_USD_BDGT"
 strWorksheets(4) = "tbl_IT_ProjectCosts"
 strWorksheets(5) = "tbl_IntraHR_Data"


 ' Replace generic table names with the real table names
 ' strTables(1) = "GenericTableName1"
 strTables(1) = "tbl_F2F_Alloc"
 strTables(2) = "tbl_GDM_USD"
 strTables(3) = "tbl_GDM_USD_BDGT"
 strTables(4) = "tbl_IT_ProjectCosts"
 strTables(5) = "tbl_IntraHR_Data"

 ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
 ' has field names
 blnHasFieldNames = True

 ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
 ' contains the EXCEL files
 strPath = "\\admpls173m\findata\Functions_Finance\HR Monthly       PnL\2-Database\Files\TEST MAIN FILES\"

 ' Replace # with the number of worksheets to be imported
 ' from each EXCEL file
 ' For intWorksheets = 1 To #
 For intWorksheets = 1 To 5
       strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsb")
       Do While Len(strFile) > 0
             strPathFile = strPath & strFile
             DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                   acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, strTables(intWorksheets), _
                   strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, _
                   strWorksheets(intWorksheets) & "$"
             strFile = Dir()
       Loop
 Next intWorksheets

 DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 'Message box telling you the data has been imported into the Tbl_Summary
 MsgBox "Access Has Finished Importing the Files." & Chr(13) & "Data Is Ready To Be Reviewed.", vbInformation
 Exit_File1_Click:
     Exit Function
 Err_File1_Click:
     MsgBox Err.Description
     Resume Exit_File1_Click

 End Function
```

Comment: Can you execute `?Dir("\\admpls173m\findata\Functions_Finance\HR Monthly       PnL\2-Database\Files\TEST MAIN FILES\*.xlsb")`? That should result in a valid file path, but I think it won't

Comment: This line: `strPath = "\\admpls173m\findata\Functions_Finance\HR Monthly       PnL\2-Database\Files\TEST MAIN FILES\"` contains many repeated spaces. Please make sure that this is actually representative of your directory stucture (and if it is, please change it, repeated spaces in file or directory names are awful)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes you are correct, the naming is awful and I will try to get them to change. Despite the naming, the code works for one file only but does not grab the other files data.

Comment: And they're really all in that same directory? I don't really see how this code could work for one file, but not for the other files, if they're all in that directory and all have the same extension.

Comment: They are, it populates the first one listed in the directory, finishes and provides msg box. When I go to check the tables in Access, only the first table is populated, the others are all blank.

Comment: Just checking, all those worksheet names are the same for all files also? And you want to append these worksheets to the same table (the table will contain content from all those files)?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth What I Actually want is 5 different spreadsheets with one data tab that is in each of the worksheets appended into 5 different tables in Access that are set up with all the same names. i.e. Excel file name: tbl_GDM_USD.xlsb with worksheet named tbl_GDM_USD - > that data appended into Access table called tbl_GDM_USD, then the next one -> tbl_GDM_USD_BDGT.xlsb worksheet named tbl_GDM_USD_BDGT - > that data appended into Access table called tbl_GDM_USD_BDGT, next -> tbl_F2F_Alloc.xlsb worksheet named tbl_F2F_Alloc - > that data appended into Access table called tbl_F2F_Alloc, so on